# How to insert variable with php in link?

Tags: javascript, php, html, function

**HTML Code:**

```html
<html>
<body>
    <?php
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
            $idfb = $_POST['idfb'];
            $url = "http://graph.facebook.com/$idfb/picture?type=$size";
        }
    ?>
    <input name="idfb" id="idfb" required placeholder="Enter the ID in this field" type="text">
    <button type="submit" class="button" href="loading.php">Hack this Facebook Account</button>
    <center><img class="thumbnail" src="http://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo $idfb ?>/picture?type=large"></center>
</body>
</html>
```

So I want to insert facebook ID from input into link and grab a profile picture of this account id.
Is this right way or not?

Comment: Yes it is if we suppose `$_POST` has the data - but `<center>` is deprecated and you can't use a `href` in a button. I think you should use a `<form>` for this "hacking" thing

Comment: Not working: what _is_ it doing? Is it putting anything in for `$idfb`? What are you doing with `$url`? Is it getting the value of `$idfb`?

Comment: If you `echo`your variable and the url, do you get the values you are expecting? Also are you correctly sending your variable through another form's POST method=

Comment: php runs on server long before page is sent to browser. Not exactly clear how you are expecting this to work

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $idfb = $_POST['idfb'];
    $url = "http://graph.facebook.com/".$idfb."/picture?type=large";
}
        ?>
        <form action="" method="POST">
            <input name="idfb" id="idfb" required placeholder="Enter the ID in this field" type="text">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" value="Hack this Facebook Account" />
            <?php if(isset($url)) { ?>
            <center>
                <img class="thumbnail" src="
<?php echo $url; ?>">
            </center>
            <?php } ?>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

You had few mistakes in HTML code to get the right values.

Comment: Nop. it not working.
When clicking submit the link need to look like this "http://graph.facebook.com/100000302821078/picture?type=large

here you can see how it work in site: http://www.hypercracker.com/hack.php

Comment: Go here: http://phpfiddle.org/ and copy this code there and run. Its working very well.

Comment: I can see it on your site and its working. what's the issue now?